# Send data to a webservices Rest from a PHP form and also save it in a MySQL database

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP form and the information saved in a MySQL database. How can I send the data to a Rest web service, at the same time the user completes the form?

This is the code of the form

```html
<form action="guardar.php" method="POST">    

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="nombre">Nombre</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="nombre" name="nombres" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">           
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="apellido">Apellido</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="apellido" name="apellidos" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required="">           
      </div>
    </div>      
    <button id="enviar" name="enviar" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>

</form>
```

Comment: "How can I send the data to a Rest webservice" Nobody can answer that without knowing the data formats which the REST server supports.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following solution

```
<?php

include('conexion.php');
// Recibimos los datos por POST 
$nombre = $_POST["nombres"];
$apellido = $_POST["apellidos"];
$tipoIdentificacion = $_POST["identificacion"];
$documento = $_POST["documento"];
$celular = $_POST["celular"];
$telefonoCasa =$_POST["telefonoCasa"];
$correo = $_POST["email"];
$carrera = $_POST["carrera"];
$modalidad = $_POST["modalidad"];


$sql = "INSERT INTO inscritos (nombre, apellido, tipoIdentificacion, documento, celular, correo, carrera, modalidad) VALUES ('$nombre', '$apellido', '$tipoIdentificacion', '$documento', '$celular', '$correo', '$carrera', '$modalidad')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql); // Se guardan los datos en la data MySql


$post = [
    'nombres' => $nombre,
    'apellidos' => $apellido,
    'documento'   => $documento,
    'telefonoCasa' => $telefonoCasa,
    'celular' => $celular,
    'email' => $correo, 

];
$ch = curl_init();
// URL del web service a cunsumir
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://dominio.com/webservice); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// POST
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post)); 
$response = curl_exec($ch); // Respuesta de Web Service
var_export($response);


?>
```